# ¿Cómo puedo saber cuando alguien visita mi página web?

Tags: php

Quiero desarrollar una página web en *PHP* con un ***panel de control de administración que me muestre el número de visitas que ha tenido la web***.
¿Cómo puedo saber cuando entran a mi web, para posteriormente persistir esa información en base de datos?

Comment: Recomendaría que inscribas tu web en [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/). Ellos registran todas las visitas a tu página web y tú puedes leer y mostrar la información a través de un plugin o a través de la API de Analytics.

Comment: Hola te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Como ha dicho mi compañero, haz una función que cada vez que entren en tu index, haga una inserción en una tabla. Esto puede dar lugar a que si actualiza 20 veces te haga 20 inserciones y te creerás que son 20 visitas. Para solucionarlo haz que una vez inserte te guarde en sesión una variable, y asi la prox vez que vaya a la función compruebe si tiene esa variable, y si la tiene no inserta.

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: revisar [answer]. Obten mas reputación para comentar.

Answer (score 2):

hace un tiempo largo utilice un scritp para tener un sistema de visitas propio.

Con esto obtinia el tipo de navegador y el sistema operativo. Aviso que no esta actualizado para los smartphone... era otra epoca, je.

```
<?php
function getBrowser() {
$u_agent     = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$bname         = 'n/i';
$platform     = 'n/i';
$version    = 'none';

// En primer lugar obtener la plataforma.
if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Linux';
}
elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Mac';
}
elseif (preg_match('/firefox/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Firefox';
}
elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Windows';
}
elseif (preg_match('/samsung/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Samsung';
}
elseif (preg_match('/android/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'Android';
}

// Siguiente obtener el nombre del agente de usuario por separado.

if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
    $ub = "MSIE";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
    $ub = "Firefox";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Google Chrome';
    $ub = "Chrome";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Apple Safari';
    $ub = "Safari";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Opera';
    $ub = "Opera";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Netscape';
    $ub = "Netscape";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Android/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Andriod';
    $ub = "Andriod";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Samsung/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Samsung';
    $ub = "Samsung";
}

// Finalmente obtener el número de versión correcto.
$known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
$pattern = '#(?<browser>'.join('|', $known).')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
    // No tenemos el número correspondiente sólo seguir
}

// see how many we have
$i = count($matches['browser']);
if ($i != 1) {
    //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
    //see if version is before or after the name
    if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][1];
    }
}
else {
    $version= $matches['version'][0];
}

// check if we have a number
if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

return array(
    'userAgent' => $u_agent,
    'name'      => $bname,
    'version'   => $version,
    'platform'  => $platform,
    'pattern'   => $pattern
);
}

//now try it
$ua = getBrowser();
$yourbrowser = "Browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .   $ua['platform'] . " <br> " . $ua['userAgent']."";
echo $yourbrowser;
?>
```

De geoip https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php guardaba en la base de datos de que pais se hacian las visitas.
La verdad no tengo todo el el sistema porque lo perdi en un disco, pero bueno recuerdo que asi fui obteniendo los datos para guardarlos y despues tener un reporte de los mismos.

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en php, pero talvez esta explicación te pueda ayudar:

Primero crear la tabla en mysql para guardar el numero de visitas(puede ser una tabla que guarda la fecha solo para mantener un registro o dato extra para las estadísticas ) y cada vez que alguien entre a una pagina de tu web, hacer que se conecte a la base de datos e inserte un nuevo registro a esa tabla indicando la hora, fecha, entre otros... Y ya cuando quieras ver cuantas visitas tienes lonunico que haces es contar o pedir cuantos registros hay en tu tabla...

Comment: Lo de guardar las fechas te puede ayudar por ejemplo ah ver cuantos vistas has resivido en un mes en concreto en un año, en la ultima semana etc...

Answer (score 0):

Como dicen los compañeros también pienso se podría hacer creando una tabla en BBDD mysql o la que uses para guardar las visitas (Con campos data, localización, pais.. lo que te interese).

La idea es, cada vez que haya una conexión, osea, cualquiera que entre en la página que tu desees, haga un insert en tu tabla de visitas.

Habrá un momento que querrás saber si las visitas son visitas reales. Me explico. Si haces insert a cada conexión, una misma persona entrará más veces repetidas y no es nuevo  usuario. Si quisieras implementar esto, puedes recuperar la IP del visitante, insertarla y  al hacer nuevos inserts comprobar si ya existía la IP, en caso de que exista puedes aumentar el contador de esa IP o bien crear una nueva entrada si es nuevo visitante.

Espero que te ayude, un saludo.

Comment: Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Existen ***varias formas de obtener información de las visitas a una página web***, lo más usado son aplicaciones externas como Alexa o Google analytics, a las que necesitas conectar vía api para obtener datos. Aquí como empezar con la API de [Google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php?hl=es-419).
Nota: si el enlace deja de funcionar usa el buscador con algo como: *"conectar php con google analytics"*.

Si quieres hacer algo interno puedes registrar y almacenar las IPs de los visitantes junto con una marca de tiempo para tener una idea aproximada de las visitas.

Si tienes usuarios que se loguean en el sistema, lo habitual es registrar el último login, es decir que se añade un campo en la tabla de usuarios y se guarda la marca de tiempo en el momento que se inicia la sesión. Para llevar más control de cuántas veces entran, se usaría una tabla aparte registrando las IDs de los usuarios y las marcas de tiempo de inicios de sesión o ejecución de cierto script, ya que la sesión puede tener una duración determinada, por ejemplo almacenar marcas de tiempo cada vez que al usuario se le cargan datos de la BD.

Los ***sistemas de registro de marcas de tiempo con IDs o IPs*** generalmente requieren de un control de intervalos para tratar de ajustar los datos lo más posible a las visitas reales, por ejemplo la misma IP almacenada con una hora de diferencia pueden considerarse 2 visitas mientras que si se registrar con 3 minutos de diferencia lo más probable es que correspondan a una única visita.